# Is this mean value theorem? (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex plane $\mathbb C$, $G$ is a region and $a,b \in G$. $G$ contains the line segment $C$ from $a$ to $b$. Now $f:G \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic. Prove that there exist $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|\le1$ and $\theta\in C$ such that $f(b)-f(a)=\lambda (b-a)f'(\theta)$

For me, it looks very like something related to mean value theorem but still i have no idea on how to prove that. Can anyone guide me or provide some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought of writing $f= \operatorname{Re}(f) + i\operatorname{Im}(f)$?

Comment: Set $g : [0,1]\to\mathbb C$, $g(t) = f(tb + (1-t)a)$ and use that $|g(s) - g(t)|\le \left(\max_{\zeta\in [s,t]}|g'(\zeta)|\right)|s-t|$.

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 1):

It is the multivariable version of the mean value theorem.

We have $f(b)-f(a)= \int_0^1 f'(a+t(b-a)) dt (b-a)$, and so
${ f(b)-f(a) \over b-a } = \int_0^1 f'(a+t(b-a)) dt$.

If $f'(z) = 0 $ for all $z \in C$ then any $z \in C$ will suffice, so
suppose $f'(z) \neq 0$ for some $z \in C$.

Let $\theta \in C$ be such that $|f'(\theta)| = \max_{t \in [0,1]} |f'(a+t(b-a))|$, and let
$\lambda = {\int_0^1 f'(a+t(b-a)) dt  \over f'(\theta)}$.
It is straightforward to check that $|\lambda | \le 1$.

Comment: Hmm. Why is $f(z) = \cos(z) + i\sin(z)$ with $a=0$ and $b=2\pi$ no counter example?

Comment: @user251257: $\lambda = 0$. ${}$

Comment: oh yeah. I am silly. Thx

Comment: @copper.hat Derive the function in the max. ;o)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: I have had a glass of wine and I never drink and derive.

Comment: I never drink and drive. ;-)

Comment: Reminds me of an old Irish public service ad: "If you drink, don't drive; but if you do, just two will do."

Comment: You should also leave away the $(b-a)$ in your definition of $\lambda$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I am still missing the derivative in your definition of $\theta$. ;-) And a closing parentheses in the definiton of $\lambda$. :P

Comment: Picky, picky :-).

Comment: Oh yeah, this I am. :-)

Comment: Reminds me of a Keynes quote: "It is better to be roughly right than precisely wrong."